# If statement operator being ignored?

Tags: java, if-statement, addition

In the following method, it doesn't do the addition for the SolarPanel correctly when the input window appears.

When I type in "Electric" followed by "Yes/yes" i get the following
Basic Price:20000
Electric Model:2000
Total:22000

but when I do "electric" + "yes/Yes" I get

Basic Price:20000
Electric Model:2000
Solar Panel:5000
Total:27000

how come?

```
public static int CalculateCost()
                    {
                        String typeOfCarCost = askCarType();
                        String SolarPanelCost = askSolarPanel();
                        int basicPrice = 20000;
                        int ElectricModel = 2000;
                        int SolarPanel = 5000;
                        int total = 0;

                        if (typeOfCarCost.equals("Electric") || (typeOfCarCost.equals("electric") && (SolarPanelCost.equals("No") || (SolarPanelCost.equals("no")))))
                                {
                                    total = basicPrice + ElectricModel;
                                    System.out.println("Basic Price:" + basicPrice);
                                    System.out.println("Electric Model:" + ElectricModel);
                                    System.out.println("Total:" + total);

                                }
                        else if (typeOfCarCost.equals("Electric") || (typeOfCarCost.equals("electric") && (SolarPanelCost.equals("Yes") || (SolarPanelCost.equals("yes")))))
                                {
                                    total = basicPrice + ElectricModel + SolarPanel;
                                    System.out.println("Basic Price:" + basicPrice);
                                    System.out.println("Electric Model:" + ElectricModel);
                                    System.out.println("Solar Panel:" + SolarPanel);
                                    System.out.println("Total:" + total);
                                }
                        else 
                        {
                            total += basicPrice;
                            System.out.println("Basic Price:" + basicPrice);
                            System.out.println("Total:" + total);
                        }
                        return total;
                    }//ends CalculateCost
```

For example, it asks:
Electric or Hybrid ( I chose Electric, this should add 2000 to the total cost)
Electric

Solar Panel (Yes or No, I chose yes. This should add 5000 to the total cost)
Yes

The console window displays this however, it doesn't do the addition for the Solar Panel.
Basic Price:20000
Electric Model:2000
Total:22000

Additionally, how can I factor in the discount of -500 on the total when both an Electric Model and Solar Panel are chosen.

The whole code is posted below.
Any advice?

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class short7 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    PrintOptions();

}//ends main

    public static String askCarType()
    {
        String typeOfCar;
        typeOfCar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Electric or Hybrid?");
        if (!typeOfCar.equals("Electric") && (!typeOfCar.equals("electric") && (!typeOfCar.equals("Hybrid") && (!typeOfCar.equals("hybrid")))))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have to choose either an Electric or Hybrid type of car.");
            typeOfCar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Electric or Hybrid?");
        }
        return typeOfCar;
    }//ends askCarType

        public static String askSolarPanel()
        {
            String wantSolarPanel;
            wantSolarPanel = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want a Solar Panel?");
            if (!wantSolarPanel.equals("Yes") && (!wantSolarPanel.equals("yes") && (!wantSolarPanel.equals("No") && (!wantSolarPanel.equals("no")))))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have to enter either Yes or No");
                wantSolarPanel = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want a Solar Panel?");
            }
            return wantSolarPanel;
        }//ends askSolarPanel

            public static int calculateDiscount()
            {
                String typeOfCarSelected = askCarType();
                String SolarPanelSelected = askSolarPanel();
                int Discount = 0;
                if (typeOfCarSelected.equals("Electric") && (typeOfCarSelected.equals("electric") && (typeOfCarSelected.equals("Hybrid") && (typeOfCarSelected.equals("hybrid") & SolarPanelSelected.equals("Yes") || SolarPanelSelected.equals("yes")))))
                {
                     Discount = 500;
                }
                else
                {
                    Discount = 0;
                }
                return Discount;
            }//ends calculateDiscount

                    public static int CalculateCost()
                    {
                        String typeOfCarCost = askCarType();
                        String SolarPanelCost = askSolarPanel();
                        int basicPrice = 20000;
                        int ElectricModel = 2000;
                        int SolarPanel = 5000;
                        int total = 0;

                        if (typeOfCarCost.equals("Electric") || (typeOfCarCost.equals("electric") & (SolarPanelCost.equals("No") || (SolarPanelCost.equals("no")))))
                                {
                                    total = basicPrice + ElectricModel;
                                    System.out.println("Basic Price:" + basicPrice);
                                    System.out.println("Electric Model:" + ElectricModel);
                                    System.out.println("Total:" + total);

                                }
                        else if (typeOfCarCost.equals("Electric") || (typeOfCarCost.equals("electric") & (SolarPanelCost.equals("Yes") || (SolarPanelCost.equals("yes")))))
                                {
                                    total = basicPrice + ElectricModel + SolarPanel;
                                    System.out.println("Basic Price:" + basicPrice);
                                    System.out.println("Electric Model:" + ElectricModel);
                                    System.out.println("Solar Panel:" + SolarPanel);
                                    System.out.println("Total:" + total);
                                }
                        else 
                        {
                            total += basicPrice;
                            System.out.println("Basic Price:" + basicPrice);
                            System.out.println("Total:" + total);
                        }
                        return total;
                    }//ends CalculateCost


                            public static void PrintOptions()
                            {
                            int printTotal = CalculateCost();
                            }//ends PrintOptions



}//ends class short7
```

Comment: `&` won't short-circuit; it does a bitwise AND (so it will evaluate both sides).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double bracket and '&&' as below:-

```java
if ((typeOfCarCost.equals("Electric") || typeOfCarCost.equals("electric")) && ((SolarPanelCost.equals("No") || SolarPanelCost.equals("no")))
                                    {
                                        total = basicPrice + ElectricModel;
                                        System.out.println("Basic Price:" + basicPrice);
                                        System.out.println("Electric Model:" + ElectricModel);
                                        System.out.println("Total:" + total);

                                    }
else if ((typeOfCarCost.equals("Electric") || typeOfCarCost.equals("electric")) && (SolarPanelCost.equals("Yes") || SolarPanelCost.equals("yes")))
                                    {
                                        total = basicPrice + ElectricModel + SolarPanel;
                                        System.out.println("Basic Price:" + basicPrice);
                                        System.out.println("Electric Model:" + ElectricModel);
                                        System.out.println("Solar Panel:" + SolarPanel);
                                        System.out.println("Total:" + total);
                                    }
```

Comment: I've added a double bracket for both the "if" and "else if" statements. And now it shows the correct total regardless for either combination uppercase or lowercase.

Answer (score 7):

I think instead of single `&` you need to have double `&&` in your if statement.

Change this:

```
if (typeOfCarCost.equals("Electric") || (typeOfCarCost.equals("electric") & (SolarPanelCost.equals("No") || (SolarPanelCost.equals("no")))))
```

to this:

```
if (typeOfCarCost.equals("Electric") || (typeOfCarCost.equals("electric") &&(SolarPanelCost.equals("No") || (SolarPanelCost.equals("no")))))
```

Similarly in rest of your `if` statements. Change that!

**On a side note:**

As RhinoFeeder commented below its important that you understand the difference between & and &&. So the difference is simple:

**&&** is **logical AND**. It evaluates the left side of the operation, if it's true, it continues and evaluates the right side.

**&** is **bitwise AND**. It evaluates both sides of the operation.

**EDIT:-**

Even after your edit you missed the **&** here

```
& SolarPanelSelected.equals("Yes")
```

Try to change your if else block like this:

```
if ((typeOfCarCost.equals("Electric") || typeOfCarCost.equals("electric")) && ((SolarPanelCost.equals("No") || SolarPanelCost.equals("no")))
{
    total = basicPrice + ElectricModel;
    System.out.println("Basic Price:" + basicPrice);
    System.out.println("Electric Model:" + ElectricModel);
    System.out.println("Total:" + total);
}
else if ((typeOfCarCost.equals("Electric") || typeOfCarCost.equals("electric")) && (SolarPanelCost.equals("Yes") || SolarPanelCost.equals("yes")))
{
    total = basicPrice + ElectricModel + SolarPanel;
    System.out.println("Basic Price:" + basicPrice);
    System.out.println("Electric Model:" + ElectricModel);
    System.out.println("Solar Panel:" + SolarPanel);
    System.out.println("Total:" + total);
}
else 
{
    total += basicPrice;
    System.out.println("Basic Price:" + basicPrice);
    System.out.println("Total:" + total);
}
```

Comment: Alright, i'll make that change now and post back with the results

Comment: To add on to the answer, I think it's important that you understand the difference between `&` and `&&`.

Comment: When I type in "Electric" followed by "Yes/yes" i get the following
Basic Price:20000
Electric Model:2000
Total:22000

but when I do "electric" + "yes/Yes" I get

Basic Price:20000
Electric Model:2000
Solar Panel:5000
Total:27000

how come?

Comment: I've made the change from & to &&, however the problem I mentioned above still occurs.

Comment: because you are not using () and && symbol properly.

Comment: Rahul Tripathi@, if(typeOfCarCost.equals("Electric")), JVM will not check further condition after '||' or condition

Comment: @AlexiaBatyn:- I have updated my answer and provided the code for if else statement. Hope that works for you!

Comment: @AlexiaBatyn:- I dont understand why you people always dont want to try even if you get the idea where you are wrong. Its not that you have not accepted my answer so I am feeling bad. Its just that I tried my best to point the areas where you were wrong!

Comment: @RhinoFeeder:- Updated that in my answer Sir!

Answer (score 0):

You use `&` in a couple of places when you should use `&&`.  Then, it always computes both sides.  This might not matter, but it's bad form.

Second, you have control of what `askCarType` will return.  Don't use `String`s.  Create an `enum`:

```
enum CarType {
    ELECTRIC, HYBRID //Include GASOLINE, DIESEL if you want.
}
```

This way, you can just use `==` instead of `equals`.  Even if you are forced to use `String`s, document which strings you are returning from `askCarType`, and only return one of `Electric` and `electric`. Any time you are checking for equality with one of two capitalized forms of a string *you control*, you are making a mistake. Do something similar with `askSolarPanel`, though you might want to use a `boolean` instead.

When you do complex boolean expressions, use parentheses.  Use them a lot for clarity.

Solar panels on cars?  Why?

Comment: I'm just following the "orders" of my lecturer. He instructed us to write the code so that it includes the option of a solar panel :D

Comment: I've written fanciful homework an exam problems myself.  Do you understand my point about you choosing the strings to return?